# How to get product stock level in fronted cart page into bigcommerce

Tags: e-commerce, bigcommerce

I am not able to get a prodduct option stock level into a cart page. 
and storefront cart API did not get product options stock level. there is another way to show stock level show  into the cart page

I tried storefront API and then to ajax call to a product page. but no luck on an options page. plz help on that

`````````````
<script>

         $.ajax({
           url:urlpasstoajax,
           type:'GET',
           success: function(data){
          console.log(data);

           var countstock =  
              $(data).find('#product_stock_level').val();stock);
            }
           }
           });
        } 
</script>
````````````
`````````````

Answer (score 0):

The stock level for product variants is returned by the product attribute Stencil utils function: https://developer.bigcommerce.com/stencil-docs/reference-docs/stencil-utils-api-reference#stencil-utils_product-attributes

You can see an example of how this works in the cart.js file in Cornerstone. When you change the option on the cart page, the function is fetching the product attribute data to make sure that the selected option is in stock:

https://github.com/bigcommerce/cornerstone/blob/d786c6ecbed5ad588ed9489f79e2226455a07b21/assets/js/theme/cart.js#L149

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I want to display product variants stock onto the cart page. can you give me an example?